# Direct install of Ubuntu into new HDD

Tags: installation, ssd

Ok, so I have search most of the questions/answers related to this, but I could not find any "suitable" to my situation. I have a laptop currently running WIN XP. I also have a brand new and empty SSD. The question is: how can I install Ubuntu in to the new SSD? I have a cable that can connect the SSD to the USB port. Can the SSD serve as the USB drive and I should just follow the instructions to install from USB drive? Since I want to replace the existing HDD with the SSD, if I follow the USB drive instalation (using the SSD), can I then just remove the HDD and replace with the SSD now, hopefully, running Ubuntu?

Comment: Well are you planing on keeping XP?

Answer (score 1):

Just burn an Ubuntu DVD or create a bootable USB stick and boot from it. At the point the installer asks how to partionize you HDD, you choose `manually` then choose your SSD.